# Is it possible to use Vercel (Next.js) + WordPress on other webserver using reverse proxy to mask URL?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, reverse-proxy, vercel

I'm trying to build my app using next.js, deploy on Vercel (`mydomain.com`) and have a path called "`/blog`" that would pull my `blog.mydomain.com` under `mydomain.com/blog`.

I was able to do it changing the WP site URL, but only the home will be available, so if I try to access, for exemple, mydomain.com/blog it's **OK**, but if I go one path down It will redirect to the original blog domain.

mydomain.com/blog -> OK, the URL is masked and it will show my WP under vercel domain.
mydomain.com/blog/hello-world -> redirects to blog.mydomain.com/hello-world

I've read a lot of documentation on vercel/next.js, I've also tried using reverse proxy, but my lack of experience with webservers made it very hard to achieve the expected result.

I've found many answers, but none of them could apply to Vercel + External WP, so I hope you could bring some light so I can see what am I missing...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewriting-to-an-external-url) to an external URL? You could setup a rewrite rule like the following: `{ source: '/blog/:slug*', destination: 'https://blog.mydomain.com/:slug*' }`.

Comment: Yes, actually I've tried every single option in Vercel/Next.js documentation, but none of them works for sub-pages.
I was able to rewrite the homepage, but homepage only. All nested URLs points to blog.mydomain.... since it's configured on my WordPress. I've tried to rewrite my WP with apache AND NGINX rules, but got 404 or 500 error pages.

Comment: Any solutions you found?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with wordpress blog under blog.example.com. It turns out the blog was adding `/` at the end of the nested routes. I solved it with following code in the vercel.json:

```
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/blog",
      "destination": "https://blog.example.com"
    },{
      "source": "/blog/:match*",
      "destination": "https://blog.example.com/:match*/"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain how is this working under /blog? The links of posts on the page `blog.example.com/all-your-posts-links` will point to same DOMAIN only `blog.example.com/other-post-link-on-the-page`. This will defeat the purpose of having `example.com/blog`.

Or am I missing something? can you share your blog link pls.

Comment: I can't, the blog wasn't mine and it was changed. You can change the links in WP. I used something like `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'blog.example.com', 'example.com/blog') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl'; UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'blog.example.com', 'example.com/blog'); UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'blog.example.com', 'example.com/blog'); UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'blog.example.com', 'example.com/blog');`